# Hiding a #div after click / play

Tags: javascript, jquery, video

**This is what I'm trying;**

```
$(document).ready(function(){
//Slides object with a time (integer) and a html string
var slides = {
0: '<div id="playdiv" onclick="vidplay()"><img src="imgs/poster1.png" style="min-height: 300px;"/></div>',
```

**How Can I keep the functionality of the video playing; onClick but also have the #div with the image inside of it; disappear after click.**

```
function vidplay() {
   var video = document.getElementById("video");
   var button = document.getElementById("play");
   if (video.paused) {
      video.play();
      (playdiv).style.display="none";
```

Library in reference: http://cuepoint.org/

**SO. What you guys are saying; is this, huh?**

```
 function vidplay() {
     var video = document.getElementById("video");
     var button = document.getElementById("play");
     if (video.paused) {
     video.play();
     $("#playdiv").hide();
```

*But this doesn't work. Instead it just stops all functionality; and the video is frozen on first frame.*

Second fix attempt.

```
0: '<div id="playdiv" onclick="vidplay()"><img id="supercoolimg" src="imgs/poster1.png" style="min-height: 300px;"/></div>',



 function vidplay() {
     var video = document.getElementById("video");
     var button = document.getElementById("play");
     if (video.paused) {
     video.play();
     document.getElementById('supercoolimg').style.display='none';
```

**Fail log. 11:59AM. 11 degrees. NYC. (Not doing this outside, but still.)**

Below is my FULL code pasted within *pastebin*.

*Can anyone advise what I'm doing wrong here? Still nothing.*

http://pastebin.com/MYJk5gv1

Most recent (fail) attempt;

```
  $(playdiv).find('img').css("display","none");
```

Comment: you want the image or the entire div to disappear, ppl are confused here.

Comment: oOOooOo. Either or; the div is only wrapping the image. So the divs contents; and / or; yes only the image.

Comment: based upon the fact that `vidplay()` is called in the `onclick`, if you hide `playdiv`, you won't have a way to fire `vidplay()`

Comment: @Michael_B thats what i was thinking

Comment: @1977 my answer and Michael_B answer are gonna work, the rest is like he said, its gonna hide the onclick making it impossible to play again...

Comment: It's not 100% necessary that I call the onclick and vidplay inline. I am essentially just trying to come up with a soluton that allows; defined slides in accordance with the var cuepoints > be clickable to PLAY the video > and once clicked / played > THAT VAR slide IMAGE / and or wrapper #div DISAPPEARS!

Comment: @Ark Dude, that shouldn't be a problem. As I plan on having an 'actual' SEPARATE / Play + Pause button. BUT; I have tried in both yours and Michals solution and nothing happens. Except the it just becomes stuck on the first slide.

Comment: you asked to hide the img , we showed you how, if this is not working there must be something else, like an extra tag or more css.

Comment: Thanks, Ark. Really appreciate it; but it still doesn't seem to solve my problem as I cannot get it to work.

Comment: Are there any error messages in the console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it.

```
function vidplay() {
   var video = document.getElementById("video");
   var button = document.getElementById("play");
   if (video.paused) {
      video.play();
      $("#playdiv").find('img').css("display","none");
   ...
```

Answer (score 1):

Add a id to the img and

```
document.getElementById('idoftheimg').style.display='none';
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use like this ;)

```
$("#playdiv").hide();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using JQuery (I assume that `pause` property and `play` function exists)

Remove `onclick="vidplay()"` declaration and define `click` event like this :

```
$('#playdiv').click(function(){
   var $video = $("#video");
   if ($video.paused) {
      $video.play();

   //Hide the div
   $(this).fadeOut(300);
});
```